# No response from minion with long-running commands

Tags: python, salt-stack, tcpdump

I have one environment where salt-master <-> salt-minion communication has been apparently well established: 4505 and 4506 TCP ports are open, key has been accepted and some functions from test module are working fine:

```
root@minion01 # telnet master01 4505
Trying 100.134.0.200...
Connected to master01.
Escape character is '^]'.

[user@master01 ~]$ salt-key -L
Accepted Keys:
minion01

[user@master01 ~]$ salt 'minion01' test.ping
minion01:
    True

[user@master01 ~]$ salt 'minion01' test.version
minion01:
    2015.8.8
```

However, when I'm trying to execute some binaries, I'm getting no response:

```
[user@master01 ~]$ salt 'minion01' cmd.script 'salt://bin/test01' args='bla'
minion01:
    Minion did not return. [No response]
```

And I've found and interesting function also from test module to debug this issues: [test.rand_sleep](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.test.html#salt.modules.test.rand_sleep)

If I run that function with debug flag:

```
[user@master01 ~]$ salt 'minion01' test.rand_sleep -l debug
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /salt/etc/master
[DEBUG   ] Missing configuration file: /home/user/.saltrc
[DEBUG   ] Configuration file path: /salt/etc/master
[WARNING ] Insecure logging configuration detected! Sensitive data may be logged.
[DEBUG   ] Reading configuration from /salt/etc/master
[DEBUG   ] Missing configuration file: /home/user/.saltrc
[DEBUG   ] MasterEvent PUB socket URI: ipc:///salt/salt/cache/.salt-unix/master_event_pub.ipc
[DEBUG   ] MasterEvent PULL socket URI: ipc:///salt/salt/cache/.salt-unix/master_event_pull.ipc
[DEBUG   ] Initializing new AsyncZeroMQReqChannel for ('/salt/pki/master', 'master01_master', 'tcp://127.0.0.1:4506', 'clear')
[DEBUG   ] LazyLoaded local_cache.get_load
[DEBUG   ] Reading minion list from /salt/salt/cache/jobs/59/be0dc5d330a8a183114e4826349b02/.minions.p
[DEBUG   ] get_iter_returns for jid 20161018122035908234 sent to set(['minion01']) will timeout at 12:20:40.920216
[DEBUG   ] Checking whether jid 20161018122035908234 is still running
[DEBUG   ] Initializing new AsyncZeroMQReqChannel for ('/salt/pki/master', 'master01_master', 'tcp://127.0.0.1:4506', 'clear')
[DEBUG   ] LazyLoaded no_return.output
minion01:
    Minion did not return. [No response]
```

And if I sniff traffic... I actually see packets going in the proper way:

```
[root@master01 ~]# tcpdump dst 100.134.0.239 -i any and portrange 4505-4506
12:24:57.051480 IP master01.4505 > minion01.49194: Flags [P.], seq 5698:5893, ack 1, win 115, length 195
12:25:02.064182 IP master01.4505 > minion01.49194: Flags [P.], seq 5893:6104, ack 1, win 115, length 211
12:25:04.296926 IP master01.4506 > minion01.49747: Flags [S.], seq 2770281963, ack 425526514, win 14600, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 7], length 0
12:25:04.297389 IP master01.4506 > minion01.49747: Flags [P.], seq 1:11, ack 1, win 115, length 10
12:25:04.297402 IP master01.4506 > minion01.49747: Flags [.], ack 11, win 115, length 0
12:25:04.297419 IP master01.4506 > minion01.49747: Flags [P.], seq 11:12, ack 11, win 115, length 1
12:25:04.297680 IP master01.4506 > minion01.49747: Flags [P.], seq 12:13, ack 13, win 115, length 1
12:25:04.297704 IP master01.4506 > minion01.49747: Flags [P.], seq 13:15, ack 13, win 115, length 2
12:25:04.302246 IP master01.4506 > minion01.49748: Flags [S.], seq 2644063969, ack 425575524, win 14600, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK,nop,wscale 7], length 0
12:25:04.302570 IP master01.4506 > minion01.49748: Flags [P.], seq 1:11, ack 1, win 115, length 10
...
```

And coming back...

```
[root@master01 ~]# tcpdump src 100.134.0.239 -i any and portrange 4505-4506
12:27:09.254011 IP minion01.49194 > master01.4505: Flags [.], ack 819763160, win 49640, length 0
12:27:11.606309 IP minion01.49782 > master01.4506: Flags [S], seq 462752770, win 49640, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 0,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
12:27:11.606671 IP minion01.49782 > master01.4506: Flags [.], ack 1832475241, win 49640, length 0
12:27:11.606856 IP minion01.49782 > master01.4506: Flags [P.], seq 0:10, ack 1, win 49640, length 10
12:27:11.607084 IP minion01.49782 > master01.4506: Flags [.], ack 12, win 49640, length 0
12:27:11.607133 IP minion01.49782 > master01.4506: Flags [P.], seq 10:12, ack 12, win 49640, length 2
12:27:11.607532 IP minion01.49782 > master01.4506: Flags [.], ack 13, win 49640, length 0
12:27:11.607608 IP minion01.49782 > master01.4506: Flags [P.], seq 12:14, ack 15, win 49640, length 2
12:27:11.611069 IP minion01.49783 > master01.4506: Flags [S], seq 462854740, win 49640, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 0,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
```

So It looks like communications are somehow suddenly interrupted but, why? How is it possible that some features from test module works and some others does not?

Thanks In advance. Any clue/hint would be appreciated.

**Update**: If I execute the salt cmd.script command with timeout flag `-t` it does work. However, in many other cases I did not need that option. Main difference observed between this case and the successful ones is the absent of following debug messages:

```
[DEBUG   ] Checking whether jid 20161019054212008948 is still running
```

Even if the minion is configured with custom keepalive settings:

```
root@minion01 # cat /salt/etc/minion | grep -v ^# | grep -i keepalive
tcp_keepalive_idle: 60
tcp_keepalive_cnt: 3
tcp_keepalive_intvl: 5
```

By the way, there is just one single network element between salt-master (master01) and salt-minion (minion01) which is the internal firewall. Everywhere is properly set the MTU to 1500.

Comment: what does `date` says on both machines? is the time running in sync?

Comment: `date` command reports identical time in both machines. They are both configured against same NTP server. Thanks for the idea.